# How To Make Sure That My Action Hook Executes Last

Tags: hooks, actions, wp-head

How can I make sure that `my_function` action hook on 'wp_head' is executing last? One hack, that I'm using, is to give `999999` (a big number) as the third argument. But maybe some other hook on 'wp_head' is giving even bigger number than this one.

```
function my_function() {
    ?>
    <style>
        .custom-class{
                  background: blue;
        }
    </style>
    <?php   
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_function', 999999);
```

Comment: How that function is related to the hook?

Comment: @Chittaranjan sorry, there was a semantic error in the code. It is fixed. I hope that it is now related to hook because of `add_action`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You define priority. It's not a hack.
Maybe it's that you're looking for is `PHP_INT_MAX` which is a PHP constant. So you can put it as priority number.

Comment: For example, if my function is hooked with PHP_INT_MAX as priority and another function is also hooked to wp_head with PHP_INT_MAX as priority then what factor will decide that who will execute last?

Comment: Functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

Comment: Chittaranjan is right. It's logically added in the same order when with the same priority

Comment: Just a little detail, I don't think he meant that using the priority param is a hack, but rather shooting an absurdly high number in the dark, where he is trying to control with a certain degree of precision that his hook comes last.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your CSS rule to apply, you must make it more specific. Of course if you add it the last one, it'll work, but if other person adds the same on the same priority, it fails. The best approach is to make something like:

`body .custom-class`

Or make it more deep specific, adding more IDs or classes to your selector.